# htaccess redirect to modified url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have multiple pages that are used to pull metadata for facebook, however they are linked to a page that is to be hidden from the public. The url that is to not be seen is:

```
test.local/university/test_name
```

The above link should redirect to:

```
test.local/content/university
```

Is there any way I can do this with a RewriteRule in htaccess? Or does it need to be done via a PHP redirect?

Apologies if duplicate.

**Update:**

This is how I resolved this problem.

```
$domain = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
$uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$url = "http://".$domain . $uri;

$parsedURL = parse_url($url);

//    search regex
$regex = "(^\/[\d]+-(.*?)/)";

//    get the matched part of the url
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'facebook.com') !== false) {
    if (preg_match($regex, $parsedURL['path'], $matches) === 1) {
        $url = $parsedURL['scheme'] . "://" . $parsedURL['host'] . "/content" . $matches[0];
        header('Location: ' . $url);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `test.local/content/university` loading same content as `test.local/content/universitytest_name`?

Comment: Yes the same content is loaded

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this...

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^test.local/content/university$    path/to/real/page.php    [NC,L]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @TomReeves - Do you need more help? If this answer was helpful to you and answered your question, please don't forget to [accept that answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).
Also see [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) and [Why is voting important?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `RedirectMatch` rule in your site root's .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(university)/[\w-]+ /content/$1
```

Comment: This works, but I have to enter every name manually (RedirectMatch 301 ^/([\w-]+)/jonathan-babin/ /content/$), which doesn't scale well as there are over 500 names. Is there any way around this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

cheers for your input. I done this in via PHP in the end.

```
$domain = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
$uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$url = "http://".$domain . $uri;

$parsedURL = parse_url($url);

//    search regex
$regex = "(^\/[\d]+-(.*?)/)";

//    get the matched part of the url
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'facebook.com') !== false) {
    if (preg_match($regex, $parsedURL['path'], $matches) === 1) {
        $url = $parsedURL['scheme'] . "://" . $parsedURL['host'] . "/content" . $matches[0];
        header('Location: ' . $url);
    }
}
```